# auto nice daemon

Tags: daemon, cgroups, nice

I know path to parent executable (launcher).

I would like to kill all other launchers without child processes (if any).

I don't know PID of child process(es).

Only kids should have **high** priority (**low** nice value)

I would like to prioritize: CPU, I/O, Network. Not just CPU.

Comment: Maybe answer with cgroups could work. I don't know.

Comment: You can expect "CentOS 8" or Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

[Ananicy](https://github.com/Nefelim4ag/Ananicy): almost what I wanted. Preconfigured for popular apps (like browser). Network is missing.

Comment: Perhaps you can show how to install & use this to solve the partial problem?